# Grouping Content Panes in Views For Theming

Tags: 7, views, theming

I've created a view for a specific content type. This view has a number of Content Panes associated with it.

I need to apply a row template file to about half these panes but the only tpl name suggestions the "Theme: Information" section gives are shared across all panes.

Is there a way to delineate certain panes for templating purposes? Machine name kind of works but I don't want to end up with `views-view-fields--machine-name-1.tpl.php, views-view-fields--machine-name-2.tpl.php, ....`

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

In Views you can change this by giving the View a name, which will change the display name from `views-view--view_id--page_1` to `views-view--view_id--my_display_name`. You can do this in the Advanced section of a view display config, and changing the 'Machine Name' value.